# Pass parameter to WordPress plugin with pretty url, mod_rewrite, .htaccess

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I told WordPress that I wanted urls to look like:
`domain.com/postname.html`

**I want to pass a parameter to a WordPress plugin. So when I get
domain.com/postname.html.2 it is supposed to be domain.com/postname.html?tubepress_page=2**

With the following the parameter is passed correctly, but not the name.

This is the `.htaccess` file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^.*([0-9]+)$ /?tubepress_page=$1
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php
</IfModule>
```

So for URL `domain.com/postname.html.2`
The above `.htaccess` basically works, it gives me the correct parameter to the script, but not the correct page, it gives me the latest WordPress post.

I think it somehow is missing the post name, but I don't know how to
specify that in the RewriteRule.

I get the same if I type:
domain.com/.2
which gives me the latest post.

So what would be good
domain.com/xyz.html.2 to be tubepress_page=2 for the page xyz
and I don't want to specify xyz.html anywhere in the htaccess file,
since I want to
try to avoid typing in things for each new post I make.

**How do I specify it so that the post name variable is taken into consideration in the RewriteRule?**

Any help on this would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try this rule:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*\.html)\.([0-9]+)$ $1?tubepress_page=$2
```

Comment: No, it does not work.

If I do:
RewriteRule ^(.*\.html)\.([0-9]+)$ $1?tubepress_page=$2 [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php
The browser is redirected from /filename.html.3 to filename.html?tubepress_page=3
which suggest the logic is correct?

Maybe it is wordpress' fault. That is does something in addition. It does the postname.html translation right, since it does not say anything about postname in the .htaccess file.